# Уточнение или нет? - "В настоящий момент (,)по заказу компании(,) мы изготавливаем"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми фразу "по заказу компании" в предложении "В настоящий момент по заказу компании мы изготавливаем инновационную станцию боковой разгрузки товаров...", в связи с тем, что это уточнение? Или же это не уточнение?

Answer (score 2):

В настоящий момент по заказу компании мы изготавливаем инновационную станцию боковой разгрузки товаров. 
Запятыми выделять не нужно. Это простое предложение, дополненное обстоятельствами времени {(Когда?) - в настоящий момент} и образа действия {(как?)(каким образом?) - по заказу компании}. "Мы изготавливаем" - это подлежащее и сказуемое. "Мы изготавливаем" " в настоящий момент" и "мы изготавливаем" "по заказу компании" одновременно. Это не уточнение, это два обстоятельства, по которым "мы изготавливаем", не зависящие друг от друга.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы подсказать, где можно почитать об этом верную информацию. Не совсем понимаю разницу между уточнением и нет. К примеру, в этом предложении используются уточнения: Маленькая, /лет восьми/, девочка принесла чай.

Comment: Почему нельзя их истолковать также, как простое предложение, дополненное обстоятельствами. К примеру: Девочка - это подлежащее. "Девочка" маленькая" и "девочка" "лет восьми" одновременно. Почему они не могут быть не зависящими друг от друга?

Comment: Можете прочитать здесь: [§ 22. Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=117#pp117)

Comment: Серж, большое спасибо!

Comment: "Не совсем понимаю разницу между уточнением и нет."  - а она и не формализована, эта разница. Строго говоря, до конца её никто не понимает. Но в данном случае ответ верен, тут трудно по-иному трактовать.

Comment: >> *Девочка - это подлежащее. "Девочка" маленькая" и "девочка" "лет восьми" одновременно. Почему они не могут быть не зависящими друг от друга?* Потому что они зависят. )) Девочка какая? – маленькая. Какая именно? – лет восьми. Уточнение в чистом виде, прямо-таки образец.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере мы имеем **неоднородные обстоятельства**, поэтому второе обстоятельство не может уточнять первое. В то же время второе обстоятельство **может быть обособлено** в связи с распространенностью, а также позицией (между подлежащим и сказуемым), удобной для обособления, например:

В настоящий момент  мы,  **по заказу этой же компании**, изготавливаем инновационную станцию боковой разгрузки товаров (авторское обособление со значением дополнительной информации).